# How to Move one Screen to Another Screen in LibGDX.?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am trying to move one screen to another screen using LIBGDX game engine.
my first Screen where i have a button, i want when i click on this button screen should be change.

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton.TextButtonStyle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ClickListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.TextureRegionDrawable;


public class MyGdxGame extends Game implements Screen,InputProcessor{
Stage stage;
TextureRegion rgn_reply;
TextButton button_reply;
TextButtonStyle reply_style;
BitmapFont font;

Game game;
Screen1 screen1;
MyGdxGame h;
float y_touched;
float x_touched;
public MyGdxGame()
{

}
public MyGdxGame(Game _g)
{
    this.game=_g;
}
@Override
public void create() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    font = new BitmapFont();


    stage = new Stage();
    Sprite sp_button =  new Sprite(new TextureRegion(new Texture("whats-app.png")));
    Sprite sp_button_active =  new Sprite(new TextureRegion(new Texture("whats-app_active.png")));
    reply_style = new TextButtonStyle(new TextureRegionDrawable(sp_button),new TextureRegionDrawable(sp_button_active),null,font);
    button_reply = new TextButton("", reply_style);
    button_reply.setPosition(55,55);
    button_reply.setSize(100, 100);
    stage.addActor(button_reply);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    button_reply.addListener(new ClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
               System.out.println("button clicked");
               game.setScreen(new Screen1());
             };
       });

}
 @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.18f,0.21f,0.27f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        super.render();
        stage.draw();
    }
@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void show() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void hide() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

This is my 2nd screen code there is nothing on this screen.

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;

public class Screen1 implements Screen{

MyGdxGame h;

public Screen1(MyGdxGame _h)
{
    this.h=_h;
}

public Screen1()
{

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.18f,0.21f,0.27f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void show() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void hide() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void pause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void resume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

this does not work properly. not showing the 2nd screen.

Comment: What is the error ?

Answer (score 1):

You can look these links:

1. https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/ScreenAndGameClasses
2. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Extending-the-simple-game

in the line `game.setScreen(new Screen1(YourGame));`

```
    //Other Code

    @Override
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
           System.out.println("button clicked");
           game.setScreen(new Screen1(game));
    };

    //Other Code
```

Comment: why? downvote my answer, I think it should explain the downvote, 1 because it is assumed that it does, downvote, has a solution that is just right and could publish your answer, and if not so, could say that is what, my answer is wrong, thanks for reading